# Forcing Django to use INNER JOIN instead of LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: django

I have implemented search in my Django application to allow searching by more than one field. This results in Django always using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, which in my case generates the wrong results. However, when I change the SQL generated from a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`, it returns the correct result.

I am thinking it has to do with the way `Q object` in my code below.

```
from django.db import models, transaction
...
def construct_search(field_name):
    if field_name.startswith('^'):
        return "%s__istartswith" % field_name[1:]
    elif field_name.startswith('='):
        return "%s__iexact" % field_name[1:]
    elif field_name.startswith('@'):
        return "%s__search" % field_name[1:]
    else:
        return "%s__icontains" % field_name


class CoreSearchMixin(object):
    """Subclasses must define search_fields = [field_1, ...field_n]
    where the field is a string, the name of a field, and can contain the following prefix characters:

    '^': the search field must start with the search term, case insensitive
    '=': the search field must exactly equal the search term, case insensitive
    '@': full-text search

    If no prefix is given, any string that contains the search field will match.
    """
    search_fields = None
    search_form_class = SearchForm

    @cachedproperty
    def search_form(self):
        return self.search_form_class(getattr(self.request, self.request.method))

    def get_query_help_message(self):
        """Returns a comma separated list of fields that are used in the search, to help the user
        create a search.
        """
        fields = []
        if self.search_fields:
            for search_field in self.search_fields:
                field = get_field_from_path(self.model, search_field)
                fields.append(field.verbose_name.title())
        return ",".join(fields)

    def get_filtered_queryset(self, queryset):
        if self.search_form.is_valid():
            self.query = self.search_form.cleaned_data['q']
        else:
            self.query = None
        if self.search_fields and self.query:
            orm_lookups = (construct_search(str(search_field).replace('.', '__'))
                           for search_field in self.search_fields)
            chained_or_queries = None
            for bit in self.query.split():
                or_queries = (models.Q(**{orm_lookup: bit})
                              for orm_lookup in orm_lookups)
                if chained_or_queries:
                    chained_or_queries = itertools.chain(chained_or_queries, or_queries)
                else:
                    chained_or_queries = or_queries
            return queryset.filter(reduce(operator.or_, chained_or_queries))
        else:
            return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        return super(CoreSearchMixin, self).get_context_data(
            search_form=self.search_form,
            query_help_message=self.get_query_help_message(),
            search_fields=self.search_fields,
            **kwargs
        )
```

How can I ensure that an INNER JOIN is used instead of a LEFT OUTER JOIN in the case of my code above?

Comment: Why don't you use Q search then? With Q search already you can search with more than one field. Can you tell me, the point of this Question, i didn't get you why do you implement this. Already Q search supports searching with multiple fields. For example, Poll.objects.filter(field1__startswith='Who',
    Q(pub_date=date(2005, 5, 2)) | Q(pub_date=date(2005, 5, 6)))

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include the SQL generated by the code you've quoted above.

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, you want to search over multiple fields. However, following the logic you have, the first result that is found in the OR sequence is returned—without returning possible subsequent matches in the `OR` sequence; remember, the `OR` operator stops evaluating upon a truthy result.

In order to convert your `OUTER LEFT JOIN`s to `INNER JOIN`s you would need to have `AND`/`OR` `Q` object permutations of search fields combinations (optimal?), or query them separately and do an intersection on the result (sub-optimal), or write the SQL yourself (sub-optimal).

PS: I've run into this issue before a writing a Datatables API wrapper for use with Django.
PS: I'd consider refactoring, and further commenting your code—specifically `get_filtered_queryset`; it took a few minutes for me to wrap my head around what was going on here.